# join two remote tables by fields that are transformed tolower

Tags: r, dbplyr

How can I join two remote tables (postgres) by a field in each table (different names) that should first be transformed `tolower()` on the db?

Here is a basic example from the docs. This example does not need `tolower()` to work, but how would you add it to make the contents of `name` and `name2` all lowercase prior to the join?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

band_db <- tbl_memdb(dplyr::band_members)
instrument_db <- tbl_memdb(dplyr::band_instruments) %>%
  rename("name2" = "name")

band_db %>% left_join(instrument_db, by=c("name" = "name2"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `tolower` has an sql translation, so you can use it with dbplyr:

```r
> library(dbplyr)
> library(dplyr)
> translate_sql(tolower("FirstName"))
<SQL> LOWER('FirstName')
```

Hence following the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64919170/7742981) answer:

```r
band_db <- band_db %>%
  mutate(lower_names = tolower(names))
instrument_db <- instrument_db %>%
  mutate(lower_names = tolower(names))

output <- left_join(band_db, instrument_db, by = "lower_names")
```

Comment: thanks, @Simon.S.A. i wonder how this can apply with a read only db. i did not set that up in my toy example, but i don't have the ability to mutate in each table before pulling locally.

Comment: Mutate does not changes the remote database. All remote tables are defined by the database query that returns the resulting table. If you call `show_query(my_db_table)` you will see the current query. I recommend you try it before and after the mutates to see the difference.